# C# Mathnet Numerics Polynomial Evaluate across an vector/array, do I have to loop?

Tags: c#, polynomial-math, mathnet-numerics

Ok, so I'm attempting to fumble my way through a Matlab source code conversion into C#. Thus far I've been able to do everything without needing to implement any loops.

data = vector of data
Fourier.Forward(data.AsArray()) takes in data and overwrites the original vector with the results.
Vector.ABS(data) calculates the absolute value across the vector
Polynomial.Fit(x.AsArray(), data.Array()) calculates and returns the coefficients for the polynomial

but now I need to plot and find the Y value based on the X. The only function I can find is

Polynomial.Evaluate, but it takes in a single X value, and returns the Y. Is there a function that will take in my entire vector or as an array, that will return a single vector/array of results?

Comment: You can use Linq's `Select`. If you have a collection of `X` in `xCol`, and `Polynomial.Evaluate` evaluates an X into a Y, you can `var yCol = xCol.Select(x => Polynomial.Evaluate(x))`. Yeah, it's effectively a loop, but it looks and acts like a vector function

Comment: @Flydog57  that worked great. Thank you. I'm going to have to look into Linq's. Is it efficient to use?

Comment: That basically does a foreach over the source collection, applying the _lambda_ (the transformation function you specified `x => Polynomial.Evaluate(x)`) to each member to create the output collection. Given that Microsoft wrote it and it gets used all over the place, you can be sure that it's tested code and pretty sure it's well written

Comment: By the way, you can read that lambda as "given an x, return Polynomial.Evaluate(x)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq's Select.

If you have a collection of X in xCol, and `Polynomial.Evaluate` evaluates an X into a Y, you can do the following:

```
var yCol = xCol.Select(x => Polynomial.Evaluate(x)).
```

It's effectively a loop, but it looks and acts like a vector function

The way it works is that the *lamba* you specified

```
x => Polynomial.Evaluate(x)
```

Is applied to each member of `xCol`, resulting in an output enumerable collection.

You can read that lambda as "given an x, return Polynomial.Evaluate(x)"